# pipe raw email message to python script

Tags: python, exim, pipe

In exim4, I use following pipe to send a message to a python script, process it, and upload it to django:

```
send_to_django_mailbox:
  driver = pipe
  command = /usr/local/bin/python /etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/send_mail.py $message_body  $message_headers_raw
  return_path_add
  delivery_date_add
```

instead of passing in `$message_body` and `$message_headers_raw` I would like to pass in the very raw message, without any substitution. How can I achieve it? I cannot find a variable `message_raw` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exim can pipe message to another process, and from that process message is accessible via `/dev/stdin` file. For example, from shell we can read message line by line like that:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line
do 
  echo (( $line ))
done < /dev/stdin
#####
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, stupid me, I should had read the documentation more carefully:

The plain message is send to the script via stdin, I don't have to pass it in via command line parameters.

in python it would be like

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    the_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Even more - you can open `/dev/stdin` for reading and your message is here. That is very useful with shell scripts where there is no `sys` module.

Comment: @Kondybas: make it an answer and I'll accept it.